# Set variable session copyonwritearraylist

Tags: mule, session-variables, copyonwritearraylist

Im new on Mule ESB and i have the next problem. I use connector "Collection Splitter" to separate a list of orders (books) to other things. When i do the checks i go back to join the books on the order with connector "Collection Agreggator". What i want is save the information of the payload in that moment in a session variable. The system dont do that. I think is posible because the type saves on the payload is "CopyOnWriteArrayList" type and i dont now if is posible save this type of list in a session variable.

Someone can be help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a set-session-variable transformer. Set the name is something of your choosing and set the value to be #[payload]. That you will maintain both your payload and have a new session variable. However be very careful when using session variables, since these are serialized when sending a Mule message over a transport. If possible, try to use flow variables.

Answer (score 0):

use the message enricher scope to achieve the same.

define the required component inside the message enricher scope.
in the enricher scope specify source as payload and the target as session variable.
try and let me know the status.